# RabbitMQ.Client Exceptions: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am a RabbitMQ newb.

I tried to run the example code from there [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html):

Code:

```
class Receive
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello",
                                 durable: false,
                                 exclusive: false,
                                 autoDelete: false,
                                 arguments: null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello",
                                 autoAck: true,
                                 consumer: consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I run the code in vs 2019
in this line:

```
using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
```

I get an error:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 127.0.0.1:5672
```

tried to change to other ports:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8080 };
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 8081 };
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 5671 };
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 5673 };
...
```

turned off the firewall, and still getting the same exception

Thanks

Comment: Is RabbitMQ actually running...?

Comment: Check if your RMQ instance is running. And the port might be different as well. If you open browser on that address you should see a page with AMQP in it